# CSS even and odd for a class

Tags: css

I am trying to implement the even / odd in css. It worked me every time. But now, because there some information between lines, I added a class to the rows.

And in this case even and odd rule is not good anymore.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4tsmk4q/2/) what I am talking about. I assumed, the odd/even will attached only for `.row` items.

Is it possible to solve this with css only, without any jQuery or script?

**CSS**

```
div.row:nth-child(odd) {background: #fff}
div.row:nth-child(even) {background: #cecece}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">Sometext</div>
<div class="row">Sometext</div>
<div class="row">Sometext</div>
<div>This div has no class</div>
<div class="row"><strong>Should be grey!!!</strong></div>
<div class="row"><strong>This should be white</strong></div>
<div class="row">This should be grey also...</div>
```

Comment: Change the none  `.row` to another element like span and use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`. https://jsfiddle.net/b4tsmk4q/8/

Comment: Or add a div container with a class, with the same CSS.
https://jsfiddle.net/b4tsmk4q/12/

Comment: @pedrodj46 No good, because the grey should be white in that case.